# Porque no me funciona el Scroll en un ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

tengo creado un ListView para mostrar archivos, pero no llega a mostrar todos los archivos

Este es el XML que contiene el ListView

**pdf_content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margen_superior"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margen_izquierdo"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margen_derecho"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margen_inferior"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y en este XML es donde lo intento mostrar.

**meses.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Meses"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/pdf_content_main" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

El listado debería dejar mostrar todos los meses, y solo se muestra lo que se ve en la siguiente imagen, y al intentar deslizar el listado apenas se mueve, solo hace un ligero movimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque no puedo hacer Scroll?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo `meses.xml` modifica la altura de `wrap_content` a `match_parent`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ...
    ...
```